# Edit all text between delimiters

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have a config file with blocks of code that need to be programmatically manipulated. These blocks are defined with "#" and closed with "#-":

```
#DATABASE
[config]
#-DATABASE
```

So I need to cut everything between these values and replace it with new config:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

current_config = '''
#DATABASE
[config = old]
#-DATABASE
'''
new_config ='''
#DATABASE
[config = new]
#-DATABASE
'''

final = current_config.replace('#DATABASE(.*)#-DATABASE', new_config)
print(final)
```

All this does is print the old config file:

```
#DATABASE
[config = old]
#-DATABASE
```

I assume for some reason the regex is not being triggered.

Comment: You are using string replacement (no wildcards), not a regex. Try `import re` and `re.sub()` instead.

Comment: Your tip worked, thank you so much! I imported re and replaced that line with final = re.sub('#DATABASE(.*)#-DATABASE', current_config, new_config)